# Migrating RCP application from Eclipse Indigo to Luna

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I'm actually trying to migrate an Eclipse RCP application from Eclipse Indigo to Luna. I follow the following article to perform the migration

https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2013/february/article3.php

I have choosen to use the "Compatibility Layer", and I have added the needed plugins.

I still have a problem, on my MANIFEST.MF, the specfic plugins of Nebula is marked as red.

[image: Plugins nebula error]

[image: Plugins nebula error]]

Do ou have any idea how to solve this problem ?

Thank you a lot

Comment: Well do you have the Nebula plugins installed? They aren't part of base Eclipse. Look in the Problems view for for detailed error messages. Why move to Luna (4.4) when Mars (4.5) is available?

Comment: Hi greg, Thanks for the repy, In fact I tried tis morning to move to Mars instead of Luna. Te problem of plugin dependencies is resolved :) I have another problem now when running the application :  org.eclipse.swt.SWTError cannot be found by org.eclipse.ui.workbench_